# How to load value into Java from Freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to get variable value from Freemarker before I generate it second time. Is this somehow possible?

I have following Java code:

```
        Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("template.html");
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

        RestClient rc = new RestClient();
        String id = "";//here i need "my_long_id_from_freemaker" value from Freemaker

        String response = rc.somemethod (id);//returns list of items

        data.put("items", response );
```

My template:

```
<#assign my_long_id_from_freemaker = "my_long_id_from_freemaker_value">
<div class="panel-body">
  <#list items as item>
 <p>${item.name}: ${item.id} <button type="button" id="${item.id}" >Details</button>
    </#list> 
</div>
```

And after page is generated for the first time, I want to be able to change value of "my_long_id_from_freemaker" and refresh page what will initiate another call of my java code.

Comment: Why don't you create an object with a method that changes its value? And then pass it in your `data` along with the `items`? You can invoke that method then from your freemarker template. (Note that this is not really recommended, logic like this should be done from the Java code, and you should only have presentation logic in your template.)

Comment: Thanks @jbx for your point of view. Did this way and that's enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need the value from the template before processing (executing) the template, the value must be already there after parsing the template. For that you can start the template with:

```
<#ftl attributes={"my_long_id_from_freemaker": 123}>
```

and then on the `Template` object you can call:

```
id = temp.getCustomAttribute("my_long_id_from_freemaker");
```